# How can I make http request on C++ without blocking the UI thread

Tags: android, c++, ios, android-ndk

I am currently developing a mobile game using oxygine/sdl/coco2d. 
But normal http request seemed blocking for rendering update(hang) to get response, I've tried a lot of c++ request library but could not find out.
Is there any http client which could apply on mobile http request without blocking the UI thread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use backcurl >> https://github.com/Taymindis/backcurl, it is purely rely on libcurl  based. You can customized the request as you like by using `bcl::setOpts(.... )`,  it is appropriate for Non blocking UI request.

Sample code

```
// Derived from example/main.cpp
void doGuiWork() {
    printf("\r %s --- %d", "Drawing thousand Pieces of Color with count elapsed ", countUI++);
}


void doUpdate() {
bcl::LoopBackFire();
}

void doRunOnUI () {
bool gui_running = true;
std::cout << "Game is running thread: ";
 bcl::executeOnUI<std::string>([](bcl::Request * req) -> void {
    bcl::setOpts(req, CURLOPT_URL , "http://www.google.com",
    CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1L,
    CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, &bcl::writeContentCallback,
    CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, req->dataPtr,
    CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "libcurl-agent/1.0",
    CURLOPT_RANGE, "0-200000"
                );
}, [&](bcl::Response * resp) {
    printf("On UI === %s\n", resp->getBody<std::string>()->c_str());
    printf("Done , stop gui running with count ui %d\n", countUI );
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(500));
    gui_running = false;
});

while (gui_running) {
    doGuiWork();
    doUpdate();
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(1000 / 16));
}
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it is really pure libcurl, I like it :)